# CSS3 Opacity - background only

Tags: html, css

I wanted to change the opacity of my navigations background color but it also changed the opacity of the links of my navigation. How do I change the opacity of my navigations background color only?

This is my style for my navigaton:

```
#navigation { 
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation li {
    padding-left: 22px;
    float: left;
}

#navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can do it like this:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
```

this changes the background color of black opacity to 0.7 without effecting anything else

Comment: Be aware that IE <= Version 8 doesn't support rgba! If you need to support these versions as well consider using a transparent background-image or try to put the navigationtext and the element which holds the background as siblings.

Answer (score 2):

By using this color:

```
background-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, .5); // black
```

This way, it will be 50% of the real color!

It filters alpha object and provides you with the part of the real color with some transparency effect.

Comment: Thank you! How do I change the opacity of your background image only?

Comment: Why don't you add the transparency in your graphic programm? :)

Comment: @MarkusI. Perhaps the opacity needs to be programmatic?